# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'odoo'

Tags: python, pycharm, odoo, odoo-14

I have installed odoo14 windows  and configured it to pycharm, but when I  try to customize anything from the .py file, the update is not happening, its showing the below error when i run the file
Error:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'odoo'
```

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

When executing python it will look in the specified locations in sys.path in order to find your imports. If you get module not found, it's because the module you are trying to access is not located in any of the sys.path directories or its subdirectories.

**So a next step of checking would be to check**:

1. Where is odoo14 installed?
2. run your file using the below snippet and see if any of the listed directories is the source directory or the parent directory of odoo14.

```py
import sys
print(sys.path)
```

If odoo14 is indeed not in any directory or subdirectory in the outputed list, you need to check the configuration of your project.

Maybe you created a project with a virtual env. and the odoo14 package is installed elsewhere?

Comment: Yeah, I followed your instructions. I found odoo 14 is in the outputed list...Still i am getting an error.

Comment: How are you executing the python script?